# How to call a model in ajax?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have an ajax function whose job is to append a row in a datatable whenever I store. The problem is when it appends, obviously, it appends what was inputted. But I want that all foreign keys to correspond to it's name.

for example..

a user's job id is 5... so in ajax i want to append that $user->job->name

can I call a model in ajax?

This is how my ajax looks like btw..

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ ('/users') }}',
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'name': $('input[name=user_name]').val(),
                    'email': $('input[name=user_email]').val(),
                    'password': $('input[name=user_password]').val(),
                    'role_id': $('#user_role option:selected').val(),
                    'team_id': $('#user_team option:selected').val()

                }}).done(function( data ) {
                    //add rows in modal
                    $('#userTable').append("<tr class='item" + data.id + "'><td align='center'><input type='checkbox' class='i-checks' name='input[]' value='"+data.name+"'> </td><td>" + data.name + "</td><td>" + data.email + "</td><td>" + data.role_id + "</td><td>" + data.team_id + "</td><td>" + data.team_id + "</td><td><a data-toggle='modal' href='#modal-edit-" + data.id +"'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a></td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' id='editUser' data-id='" + data.id + "' data-name='" + data.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button></td></tr>");
                    //clear the modal
                    $("#modal-add-user").find("input,select").val('').end();

   });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, are you trying to return the job name as part of the Ajax request? 

If so you'll need to do the lookup in your controller (via Job::find(id) if you know the id) and return their name as part of the response object in the same way as you'd do it in a normal request.

Comment: @DaveL yes that's what I'm asking! Is this how to return it from the controller to ajax?

            $user->save();
            $equivalents = $user->role->name;
            return response ()->json ( $user, $equivalents );

Comment: That's pretty close, I'll write up a very basic example of what I'd do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get back both the user & job details you'll need to implement something like but not the same as (please use proper input & exception handling) this:

**Laravel Controller:**

```
public function add(Request $request) {
  $user = new User(); 
  // Validate & add user, make sure you validate relationship id's
  $user->save();

  return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'roleEquivalents' => $user->role->name]); // This returns a nicely structured object
}
```

See Laravel's [HTTP Response documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses) for more information on returning JSON objects.

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{ ('/users') }}',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'name': $('input[name=user_name]').val(),
                'email': $('input[name=user_email]').val(),
                'password': $('input[name=user_password]').val(),
                'role_id': $('#user_role option:selected').val(),
                'team_id': $('#user_team option:selected').val()

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // You should throw an error from Laravel if it failed validation
            }}).done(function( data ) {
                if (data) { // If it failed we don't have data
                    var user = data.user;
                    var roleEquivalents = data.roleEquivalents; // This is your role name

                    //add rows in modal
                    $('#userTable').append("<tr class='item" + user.id + "'><td align='center'><input type='checkbox' class='i-checks' name='input[]' value='"+user.name+"'> </td><td>" + user.name + "</td><td>" + user.email + "</td><td>" + user.role_id + "</td><td>" + user.team_id + "</td><td>" + user.team_id + "</td><td><a data-toggle='modal' href='#modal-edit-" + user.id +"'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a></td><td><button class='edit-modal btn btn-info' id='editUser' data-id='" + user.id + "' data-name='" + user.name + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit</button></td></tr>");
                    //clear the modal
                    $("#modal-add-user").find("input,select").val('').end();
                }

  });
```

It also looks like you have another Team object, you can return it the same way.